# Unity Error: Assertion failed on expression: 'std::abs(det) > FLT_MIN' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) when colliding too hard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like when the error occurs

[image]

So in my marble rolling game, sometimes when the player (the Sphere) collides too hard with another object the game freezes and the Error message fills my error message box instantly.

I tried looking up exactly what the error meant, but to no avail so if anyone knows where to find such information please point me in the right direction :)
I'd rather not implement a max speed as that kind of takes away from the fun of the game since speed controll will be a big part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of the error is that the absolute value of whatever `det` is, isn't superior as whatever `FLT_MIN` is in the unity system code.

You might want to take a look at this thread.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityengine-guiutility-processevent-int32-intptr.514797/#post-6935341

or this one
https://forum.unity.com/threads/assertion-failed-on-expression-std-abs-flt_min.883201/